# Posting image + status with the Twitter API using php

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I ended up using codebird and not TwitterAPIExchange.php. Please see my answer.

[TwitterAPIExchange.php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php)

I am racking my brain trying to figure out why my code is not working. I am able to post a status update fine to twitter but when I try and add an image it seems to never post it with the status.

With the many [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550473/post-status-image-with-twitterapiexchange-on-twitter) about this I have read I have tried them all applying the media examples and none seem to work.

One thing is that many of these posts refer to the API call url being `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json` which according to [this article](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media) is depreciated.

The new URL "I think" is just `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json`

At this point the status uploads fine, the image never does. Can anyone help me with my code please.

```
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "***",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "***",
    'consumer_key' => "***",
    'consumer_secret' => "***"
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

$requestMethod = 'POST'; 

$twimage = '60001276.jpg';

$postfields = array(
    'media[]' => "@{$twimage}",
    'status' => 'Testing Twitter app'
);

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$response = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                   ->setPostfields($postfields)
                   ->performRequest();

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post status + image with TwitterAPIExchange on Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24550473/post-status-image-with-twitterapiexchange-on-twitter)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up not being able to use this method and found a more current solution. The one thing I learned about using php to tweet images with a message is that you have to load the image first up to twitter in which the API will return a `media_id` back to you. That `media_id` is associated with the image. Once you have the `media_id` back then you associate that ID with your message and send the message with the `media_id`'s. That made the code make more sense once I learned that.

I used [codebird](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) instead to achieve tweeting with php.

All you have to do is create a function like so

```
function tweet($message,$image) {

// add the codebird library
require_once('codebird/src/codebird.php');

// note: consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, and accessTokenSecret all come from your twitter app at https://apps.twitter.com/
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("Consumer-Key", "Consumer-Secret");
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken("Access-Token", "Access-Token-Secret");

//build an array of images to send to twitter
$reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
    'media' => $image
));
//upload the file to your twitter account
$mediaID = $reply->media_id_string;

//build the data needed to send to twitter, including the tweet and the image id
$params = array(
    'status' => $message,
    'media_ids' => $mediaID
);
//post the tweet with codebird
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

}
```

It's important when you download the API you make sure that `cacert.pem` is located in the same directory as `codebird.php` which comes with the download. **Don't just download** `codebird.php`

Also [keep in mind](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media#keepinmind) Twitter's guidelines for images and videos relating to sizes and parameters.

Make sure you have at least php version 5.3 and curl enabled on your server. If you are not sure what you have you can create any `.php` file and add `phpinfo();` and that will tell you everything that your php config has.

Once you have that all in place then all you have to do to send a tweet with codebird is

```
tweet('This is my sample tweet message','http://www.example.com/image.jpg');
```

Comment: I love it that I was having the exact issue again and I forgot about this and when I searched Google for an answer I find my own solution almost 2 years later lol

Comment: That's just awesome! Thanks for the solution.